# ASP.NET MVC users not being copied over on publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, and I'm trying to convert a very simple ASP.NET application to MVC with authorization.

I have it working locally just fine, but when I publish to IIS, the users database is apparently not copied over correctly (even though it is running on the same machine that I am developing it on)

It does not appear to be a database access issue, since when I create a new user using the Register link I can log in just fine. The problem is, all the users (and their associated roles) I created using the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool aren't being recognized. The error message it gives me is a simple "log in or password is incorrect" - there's nothing about not being able to access the database or anything like that.

Does anyone know where I should look for the source of this problem, or has anyone else had this problem before?

Potentially releveant additional information:

When I first published the project, I got an error in my web.config that said "ApplicationServices" was already defined, preventing me from accessing any page on the site. I "fixed" this in a manner that would be called "hacky" only if someone was trying to be polite - I added "`<remove name="ApplicationServices" />`" right above it, so that portion of the web.config looks like this:

```
<remove name="ApplicationServices" />
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Roles and Users are partitioned by ApplicationName.  Check the `aspnet_Applications` table and compare that to what you see in `aspnet_Roles` and `aspnet_Users`.

[This post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx) by Scott Guthrie explains what is probably happening, and how to configure the ApplicationName on your providers.